# How to make JS store random elements in cache?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I have this code:

```
<span id="result"></span>



        <script>
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2;
        </script>
```

Its working fine generating a number between 2 and 6, but I would like to store that number in the user's cache, so if he reloads the page the same number will display. But I would also like that if the user go to a different URL, but with the same code, then a different number displays.

In sum:

If the user first load my website and number 3 is generated, then number 3 is displayed, if the user returns to the same website the number 3 will keep been displayed, but if the user goes to another URL within my website with the same code, then it should generate another number.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the random number in the user's localStorage and map it to the current URL:

```
const stored = localStorage[location.href]
const number = stored || Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = number

if ( !stored ) localStorage[location.href] = number
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
// Change yousite.com
let lastSite = document.referrer.search(/yoursite.com/gi);

if(lastSite =! -1) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('random');
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem('random', Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('random');
}
```